# Как использовать Vue Root вместо Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex, quasar.js, quasar-framework

Всем привет. Я слышал, что можно использовать Vue Root в качестве альтернативы VUEX, хочу попробовать на практике на небольшом проекте, но не могу понять как это правильно реализовать, а главное в чём преимущества такого подхода? Прошу привести в качестве примера кусочек кода и рассказать зачем и для чего это нужно. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Какая альтернатива Vuex и как для этого можно использовать состояние Vue Root объекта?

Многие уже перешли на такой подход, я тоже в своём проекте собираюсь.
Делается простой JavaScript объект с данными которые мы считаем состояние приложения.
Пример:

```
export default {
   userName: null,
   userRoles: [],
   itemsNumber: 0,
   someObject1 : {...},
   module1: {...},
   module2: {...},
}
```

В момент создания `Vue` `Root` объекта наш `store` объект мы передаём в `data` `Vue` `Root`.

```
import store from "store";

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    store: store  // можно сократить на просто data: {store}
  }
})
```

После такой конструкции наш `store` стал реактивным, и где бы в приложении мы не использовали данные из него они будут автоматически меняться при изменении данных в `store`.

Как теперь получить доступ из любого места нашего приложения к нашему `store`.
Есть несколько вариантов:

1. В `script` части каждого компонента использующего `store` делаем `import store from "store";`
2. Прописать во Vue прототип (здесь я не обсуждаю вопрос идеологии правильно так делать или нет).

```
import store from "store";
Vue.prototype.$store = store;
```

Если речь идёт о [Quasar-Framework](https://quasar.dev) то делаем это в папке `boot` в соответствии с [документацией](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/cli-documentation/boot-files#Examples-of-boot-files).

### В чём смысл такого подхода?

- Очень удобный и простой когда хранилища `store`. Объекты, подобъекты, методы объектов и всё. Без разделения на действия `actions` и мутации `mutations`.
- Более простая модульность `store`. Модуль достаточно просто подключить как дочерний объект `store`.
- Не требует никаких дополнительных специфических `Vuex` знаний, это простой `JavaScript`. Бери и делай.
- Не требует дополнительного времени на обучение, а в последствии для вспоминания.
- Более простая структура хранилища.
- Более простой и нативный способ вызова методов. Не через `commit`, `dispatch`, а просто обычный вызов `JavaScript` метода.
- И многое другое.

**Данный метод покрывает все (или почти все) возможности Vuex.**

- Модульность
- Реактивность
- Наличие синхронных и асинхронных методов
- Геттеры (делаются через блок `computed` `Root` объекта)

```
import storeGetters from "storeGetters ";

var app = new Vue({
  ...
  computed: {
    ...storeGetters  // распаковываем гетеры сюда
  }
})
```

Comment: Благодарю за столь развёрнутый ответ!

Comment: А минусы? Зачем тогда сделали Vuex?

Comment: @doox911 Когда делал Vuex не знал что есть другие варианты. Минусов варианта с vue root не знаю.

Comment: Мне всё таки кажется что это неправильно, неправильно так использовать глобальное хранилище, для таких целей и был создан `Vuex`.  Но однозначно ответ хороший !

Comment: Минус данного подхода в том, что это всего лишь хранилище данных, но нет централизованного способа обработки данных, через действия. Так что для простых проектов, там где не требуется постоянно использовать действия над данными из разных источников - подойдёт, но для более крупных проектов, данных подход будет только тормозить разработку. Так же в SPA разработке такое ещё подойдёт, но для SSR уже нет, потом что там нужно делать дегидрацию данных.

Answer (score 1):

### Решение на Vue.observable()

```
import Vue from "vue";

// Модуль 1
const module1 = {
    var1: "hihi1",
    var2: "hihi2",
    num1: 144,
    setVar1(st, num) {
        return module1.var1 = (st + ":").repeat(num);
    }
}

// Модуль 2
const module2 = {
    xxx: "mmm1",
    yyy: "mmm2",
    zzz: 144,
    addOneZzz(val) {
        return module2.zzz += val;
    },
    testCrossModuleMethod() {
        module1.num1 = 10000;
    }
}

// Корневой объект
const rootObj = {
    data1: 100,
    data2: "test"
}

// Наше хранилище
const store = {
    ...rootObj,
    module1,
    module2
}

// Делаем наше хранилище реактивным
Vue.observable(store);

// Теперь можно использовать из любого компонента через this.$store
Vue.prototype.$store = store;
// Для Quasar логику этой строки надо класть в boot


export default store;
```

Comment: Vue.observable больше нет в VUE3, так что скоро этот способ будет не актуален. Ждём решения для VUE3! =)

Comment: Всегда можно в дату корневого элемента положить. А почему убрали? Как-то нелогично. Там и обратная совместимость должна быть, и вообще штука очень полезная.